# How can i create iTextSharp pdf in Hindi font?

Tags: itext

I am trying to build desktop application for Hindi PDFs in c#. But the Unicode encoding is not well supported.Any idea to fix this.

```
string ARIALUNI_TTF = path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");

bf = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TTF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
```

Can `Identity_H` will give support for Hindi Encoding?

Comment: Can you edit your text and include the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Hindi is not supported yet. A font like mangal.ttf, that supports the Devanagari script, will show you in iTextSharp the glyphs but not the ligatures. Work is being done on the Indic front not only for Hindi support but also for Telegu, Gujarati and others.

Comment: So is there any solution for Hindi or should I give up?

Answer (score 0):

You basically require support for Asian Characters. A similar thread can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228657/how-to-configure-itext-to-support-asian-characters)(stackoverflow). The implementation revolve around usage of `BaseFont` (use `createFont` method), which indicates using font and appropriate encoding. You can find the example on the official site of iText [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=201). Note that the example is in Java, but the same implementation is available in .Net as well.